# Save entities in service

Tags: architecture, doctrine, symfony

I am using symfony and doctrine in project. I
 have some services for manipulating data and saving  it into database. If I call 2 or more services (e.g. service for calculating and saving some value and service for notifying client via email and saving this email) in one action, then multiple transactions will be done. Queation: is saving data inside service is bad practice? Should I use service for manipulating only and save entities in controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not a bad practice.

You can inject the entity manager to your service and do it in the service.

Sometimes you will only need to call the `$em->flush();` in your controller if your service is called more than once to avoid call it more than once.

You can also just flush one entity in your service with `$em->flush($entity);` the other persisted entities will stay in the queue for the final flush.

Comment: Why down vote ? What can I add ?

Comment: I don't know, what you say is true, I vote up :)

Comment: Some user which don't like short answers ...